# How to use a Java Swing Timer to do different things every time it fires?

Tags: java, swing, timer

What can do to have a Swing Timer object fire every 2 seconds for ten times and do a different thing in each firing? Using:

```
// task one

int delay = 2000;

Timer swingTimer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

         // task two
    }
});
swingTimer.start();
```

only enables me to do two things. But I want to use the timer to execute one chunk of code, wait 2 seconds, execute another chunk of code, wait another 2 seconds, do another thing and so on and so forth for like 10 consecutive tasks. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use some kind of counter in your `actionPerformed` method to determine which cycle your up to....

```
private int cycle = 0;

//...

Timer swingTimer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        switch (cycle) {
            case 0:
                // Task #1
                break;
            case 1:
                // Task #2
                break;
            case 2:
                // Task #3
                break;
            default:
                // All done...
                ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
        }
        cycle++;
    }
});
```

You could set up a new non-repeating `Timer` at the conclusion of each `actionPerformed`, seeding it with the next `ActionListener`/task to be executed, but this can get messy quickly...

This is basic concept of the idea.  You could devise a common `interface` for each task, add them to a `List` of some kind and simply use `list.remove(0)` to pop the next one of the `List` and execute it.  You would continue until the `List` was empty.

Comment: ALLAH RAZI OLSUN. ALLAH TUTTUGUNU ALTIN ETSİN.

Answer (score 2):

```
private int cycle;

Timer swingTimer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        controller.callMethod(cycle); // controller decides what to do
        cycle++;   
    }
});
```

And don't forget to stop the timer after it completes a desired number of cycles.